# Access/SQL Server Stored Procedure Search Query - Null values

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, null

I have transferred my Access data tables to SQL server, whilst still wanting to use Access for the front end. This all worked well, but has since made the queries run slower. The one that runs slowest is a query to search for records.

Therefore I am in the process of converting the query into a SQL stored procedure, and it is almost working, from help I have had here. The search form currently has 2 search fields (firstname and surname), but this will expand to more search fields once I can resolve the issue.

The issue I am facing is dealing with null values in the search fields. For example if the user enters a string of text in both the firstname field and surname field the query returns the correct results. However, if either f the search fields are left blank. The query does not work, and you get an error debugging message.

SQL Stored procedure:

> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ZSearch]
>
> @FirstName varchar(100), @Surname varchar(100)
>
> AS BEGIN
>
> SELECT [First name], [Surname] FROM [Names] Where  ([First Name] LIKE
> '%' + @FirstName + '%') and ([Surname] LIKE '%' + @Surname + '%')
>
> END

Then in Access, I have a pass through query which is:

> EXEC ZSearch

Then Finally, on my form, I have a button which runs the following VB on click:

> Private Sub Command4_Click() Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
>
> ```
> Dim Firstname As String
> Dim Surname As String
>
> Firstname = [Forms]![Search]![SearchFirstName]
> Surname = [Forms]![Search]![SearchSurname]
>    
> With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
>     .SQL = "EXEC ZSearch " & Firstname & ", " & Surname 'Debug.Print .SQL
>     Set rst = .OpenRecordset()
>     DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPassR" End With End Sub
> ```

Please could someone assist me with how to deal with null values in the search fields. I think it needs to say that if the search field is blank, treat it as a wildcard, and if it isn't blank then use what is in there.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) or you can add where clauses like this:

```
-- WHERE ([First Name] LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@FirstName, '') + '%')
WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR [First Name] LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have amended my SQL Stored procedure code to read:
Where  ('@'FirstName is Null OR [First Name] LIKE '%' + '@'FirstName + '%') and ('@'Surname Is Null OR [Surname] LIKE '%' + '@'Surname + '%')

However, when I click the button on the form in Access, without entering any text to the Surname field , I get the debugger, and it highlights the following code:
    Surname = [Forms]![Search]![SearchSurname]

Any ideas how I can resolve this please, many thanks

Comment: @AnthonyAllsopp Now you're asking a question about how the Access development environment works. Presumably the debugger provides you some information about why it interrupted the application and stopped on that line. So - did it and, if so, what info did it provide?

Comment: Hi, the debugger says run-time erro '94: Invalid use of Null. When I click on debug, it highlights the following line    Surname = [Forms]![Search]![SearchSurname]